# Can UITextField have suggestions when autocorrect is no?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

`UITextInputsTraits` protocol conformed to by `UITextField` and `UITextView` has the property `autocorrectionType` with enum values `default`, `no` and `yes`.

For a particular `UITextField` I would like to have autocorrect turned off (so that automatic substitutions are not made). *However*, I'd like completion *suggestions* to still be shown above the keyboard. When I set `autocorrectType` to `no`, suggestions are no longer shown.

Is it possible to disable autocorrect, but still have suggestions shown?

Comment: Those suggestions you are talking about **ARE** auto correct AFAIK.

Comment: :-) I don't think so? auto-corret will automatically correct "speling" in to "spelling". It'll also suggest "sprout" and "splendid" and "spelling" when I've got to "sp…" in my text entry. I want the later part, but not the former. So, suggestions, but no automatic correction or completion.

Comment: It actually suggests "Sp" "Space" and "Splendid" once I've typed "Sp", but you get the gist!

Comment: No, I mean, they are part of the auto correct feature. You can't separate them... I think.

Comment: :-) That certainly appears to be the case, but I'm not certain, hence the question.